# Cannot update "Updating dependencies (including require-dev)" with composer update -v

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Cannot update "Updating dependencies (including require-dev)" with composer update -v

> Use Windows 7 PHP: 5.4.7 OpenSSL enabled for CLI Composer version
>   c93aecee4d3998d17a1986f042187d38dd394397

Getting error:

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\partner-portal>composer update -v
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

  [ErrorException]
  zlib_decode(): data error

Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:166
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
 zlib_decode() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:166
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:76
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:541
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:278
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->whatProvides() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:240
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:229
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:179
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->addRulesForPackage() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:274
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->getRulesFor() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:166
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:446
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:208
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:103
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:882
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:212
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:119
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar:15


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [
-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

**Edit: added composer.json ->**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "composer/composer": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "process-timeout": 5000
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it looks like Composer can't unzip something. Can you clear your cache directory (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Also are you just downloading packages from packagist.com or do you have your own repository, or using local zip files?

Comment: Thanks for your query, yes clear cache directory and i have no own repo or no local zip. Its only works fine when i delete all cache and vendor folder. and then execute "composer install". But after that when i execute "composer update" then got this error.

Comment: Yes may be its downloading packages from packagist.com

Comment: And does clearing the data in "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Composer" have any effect?

Comment: Yes i did it. Not only that uninstall and install composer also.

Comment: Can you post your composer.json or at least the requires and requires-dev part of it?

Comment: added composer.json in question body.

Comment: It works for me - you should probably report it as an issue at https://github.com/composer/composer/issues if it's still happening.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138319/composer-freezing-when-installing-symfony-vendors/17143242#17143242).

```
zlib_decode(): data error
```

Please work through the list of possible solutions i replied over there.

Furthermore make sure neither your composer.json nor composer.phar contain a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) plus both are UTF-8 encoded.

Show more debug messages by using

```
composer -vvv update
```

Please try changing the if-statement in **Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php** starting [**line 164**](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php#L164) to

```
if ($decode) {
    $result = file_get_contents('compress.zlib://data:application/octet-stream;base64,'.base64_encode($result));
}
```

You can use [**koto/phar-util**](https://github.com/koto/phar-util) to extract / re-build your composer.phar.

Comment: Yes, i use "composer diagnose" command but found all OK state. And composer.json nor composer.phar contain both are UTF-8 encoded.